# SQL SELECT Cities

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have that homework to write a SQL query that:

1. Selects countries where a total number of inhabitants (population) in all the cities is greater than 400
2. Selects names of countries that have no buildings at all.

There is a tables definitions

[image: http://imgur.com/hLZZ90F]

I)

```
SELECT c1.Name
FROM Country c1
JOIN City c2 ON (c1.CountryID = c2.CountryID)
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT *
          FROM City
         WHERE Population < 400)
;
```

Why isn't this correct ? I'm not getting any records.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [SQL subqueries Cities,Countries,Buildings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763824/sql-subqueries-cities-countries-buildings)

Comment: sory for duplicate, i have deleted that

Comment: Do not delete a question you've asked earlier just to repost the same question...

Comment: ok, i will remember, i'm newbie here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, this one works for the first case:

```
select *
from Country co
where 400 < all ( 
            select ci.Population 
            from City ci 
            where ci.CountryID = co.CountryID
            )
```

For the second case:

```
select *
from Country co
where 0 = (
    select COUNT(1)
    from City ci 
        JOIN Building B ON B.CityID = CI.CityID
    where ci.CountryID = co.CountryID
    )
```

Comment: @StefanOgur: if the answer worked for you, I'd appreciate it if you upvote it or mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot but i cant upvote becouse my reputation

Comment: it's ok because you've marked it as accepted, that's the way you can participate as an answerer